# PLSQL form insert error, can someone help me? I have no clue

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, plsqldeveloper

I have this code where I want to add some inserted values, sum them and insert in a specific column. But I am getting an error after an error. And I think this is the final one, but I have no clue. Good someone help me out? Added a screenshot with more information.

My code:

```
DECLARE 
BEGIN   
INSERT INTO thuiswerk_declaratie    (MNR, WNR, UREN_GEWERKT, TOTAAL_BEDRAG)
                
VALUES                  (:P8_MNR, 
                         :P8_WNR, 
                         :P8_TOTAAL_AANTAL_UREN (:P8_MAANDAG_UREN +
                                              :P8_DINSDAG_UREN +
                                              :P8_WOENSDAG_UREN +
                                              :P8_DONDERDAG_UREN + 
                                              :P8_VRIJDAG_UREN), 
                         :P8_TOTAAL_BEDRAG (:P8_TOTAAL_AANTAL_UREN * 0.2)
                    );
END;
```

[Printscreen of code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUuHd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is " :P8_TOTAAL_AANTAL_UREN"  and ":P8_TOTAAL_BEDRAG" ? They are bind variables in apex, so they contain a string (not a function name) However, looking at your code, it seems you are trying to reference a function in a bind variable which will give that error you see. Most probably this is just a syntax error, you could give this a try:

```
DECLARE 
BEGIN   
INSERT INTO thuiswerk_declaratie    (MNR, WNR, UREN_GEWERKT, TOTAAL_BEDRAG)
                
VALUES                  (:P8_MNR, 
                         :P8_WNR, 
                         :P8_MAANDAG_UREN + :P8_DINSDAG_UREN + :P8_WOENSDAG_UREN + :P8_DONDERDAG_UREN + :P8_VRIJDAG_UREN, 
                         :P8_TOTAAL_AANTAL_UREN * 0.2
                    );
END;
```

If you really want a function, then you could do one of the following: Note that these are more complex solutions.

Option 1:

You're using apex. Best practice to handle this is to create a computation that would calculate the page item for column UREN_GEWERKT and another one for for column TOTAAL_BEDRAG.
Your pl/sql block would then be:

```
DECLARE 
BEGIN   
INSERT INTO thuiswerk_declaratie    (MNR, WNR, UREN_GEWERKT, TOTAAL_BEDRAG)
                
VALUES                  (:P8_MNR, 
                         :P8_WNR, 
                         :P8_TOTAAL_AANTAL_UREN, 
                         :P8_TOTAAL_BEDRAG 
                    );
END;
```

You could also use the build-in form region to do all the magic for you in this case.

Option 2:

Assuming you have (1) a pl/sql function total_hours that return a value of the same datatype as thuiswerk_declaratie.UREN_GEWERKT and takes 5 arguments (1 per day of the week and (2) another function total_amount that returns a value of the same datatype as thuiswerk_declaratie. TOTAAL_BEDRAG  and takes 1 argument you could write your pl/sql block as:

```
DECLARE 
BEGIN   
INSERT INTO thuiswerk_declaratie    (MNR, WNR, UREN_GEWERKT, TOTAAL_BEDRAG)
                
VALUES                  (:P8_MNR, 
                         :P8_WNR, 
                         total_hours (:P8_MAANDAG_UREN +
                                              :P8_DINSDAG_UREN +
                                              :P8_WOENSDAG_UREN +
                                              :P8_DONDERDAG_UREN + 
                                              :P8_VRIJDAG_UREN), 
                         total_amount (:P8_TOTAAL_AANTAL_UREN * 0.2)
                    );
END;
```

Comment: Aha I think I understand it. So what you are saying is that I need two functions like total_hours and total_amount. To calculate :P8_TOTAAL_AANTAL_UREN and :P8_TOTAAL_BEDRAG and then return them? Isn't my code working because the page items are strings and no variables?

Comment: Sorry just updated my solution - I think you just have a syntax error. Why would you need a function if you're just adding the values. if it helps I can put my first answers back

Comment: Hey, np. It would be helpful though. If it's a syntax error, how could I troubleshoot the code then? Or is it the system that causes the error?

Comment: Put original answer back, merged with new one. The error tells you exactly what the problem is. An insert statement takes a comma separated list of values. One of those columns can be a function (explicit function, not a bind variable). The error tells you it is expecting a function. You passed a bind variable.

Comment: Thank you Koen, it really helped. I have it working now!

Comment: Graag gedaan ;)